# Combination of invertible linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

This is my homework, it reads as follows:

> Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $m \times m$, let $B$ be a matrix of
>      order $m \times n$.  Prove in two different ways that if $A$ is invertible,
>      then homogeneous systems $B\vec{x} = 0$ and $AB\vec{x} = 0$ have the same
>      solution space.

My "idea" for solution is to say that $A$ represents a linear transformation and since $A$ is invertible, then this transformation is one-to-one and onto.  Hence, basically, linear transformation given by $B$ is the one that "matters".  Even if this were true, this, obviously, isn't formal enough.  I'd appreciate any help in making this more formal (or disproving it).

Comment: I like your idea. Take $ABx=0$ and multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$. Then do something similar in the other direction.

Comment: For the second method, you might try using the rank-nullity theorem and the fact that $\text{rank}(AB) = \text{rank}(B)$.

Comment: @Jonas oh, indeed, that would work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $B{x}=0$. Multiply by $A$ in both sides, $AB{x}=0$.

Reciprocally, if $ABx=0$, multiply by $A^{-1}$ (that exist because is invertible), then $Bx=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the space of the solutions of $B\vec{x}=0$ and $Y$ the space of solutions of $AB\vec{x}=0$. Then you want to show that $X=Y$, namely:

1) $X\subset Y$ i.e. If $\vec{x}$ satisfies $B\vec{x}=0$ then $AB\vec{x}=0$ and

2) $Y\subset X$ i.e. If $\vec{x}$ satisfies $AB\vec{x}=0$ then $B\vec{x}=0$.

--

For 1: follows directly.

For 2: you multiply with $A^{-1}$.